# Turn convolution filters into band matrices efficiently without support of strides

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to implement the Lightweight Convolution module from [this paper](https://openreview.net/forum?id=SkVhlh09tX) in Tensorflow. According to the authors on page 3 section "Implementation", they convert the convolution filters of size `HxK`, where `H` is the number of heads (e.g. 16) and `K` the size of the kernel (e.g. 3) into band matrices of shape `B*HxTxT` where `B` is the batch size (e.g. 64) and `T` is the sequence length (e.g. 10). By band matrix they mean that the entries outside of the kernel will be zero.

According to the [official implementation](https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/master/fairseq/modules/lightweight_convolution.py#L209) in Pytorch (Fairseq) of the lightweight convolution module, the way that its implemented is by creating a zero tensor of size `(B*H)xTx(T+K-1)` and then using the `as_stride` function, copy the kernel wights (where before you tiled, reshaped and transposed them to size `(B*H)xTxK`) into the zero tensor in a sliding window fashion over the last dimension `(T+K-1)`. To give an example:

```
B = 64
T = 10
K = 3
H = 16

kernel = torch.ones(B*H, T, K) # torch.Size([1024, 10, 3])

kernel_expanded = kernel.new_zeros(B*H, T, T+K-1, requires_grad=False) # torch.Size([1024, 10, 12])

kernel_expanded.as_strided((B*H, T, K), (T*(T+K-1), T+K, 1)).copy_(kernel) # torch.Size([1024, 10, 12])

''' 
Results before as_strided:

kernel_expanded[0,0,:] = [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
kernel_expanded[0,1,:] = [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
kernel_expanded[0,2,:] = [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
...
kernel_expanded[0,9,:] = [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]

kernel_expanded[1,0,:] = [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
kernel_expanded[1,1,:] = [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
kernel_expanded[1,2,:] = [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
...
kernel_expanded[1,9,:] = [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]

Results after the as_strided:

kernel_expanded[0,0,:] = [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
kernel_expanded[0,1,:] = [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
kernel_expanded[0,2,:] = [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
...
kernel_expanded[0,9,:] = [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.]

kernel_expanded[1,0,:] = [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
kernel_expanded[1,1,:] = [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
kernel_expanded[1,2,:] = [0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
...
kernel_expanded[1,9,:] = [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.]

'''
```

The question now is that since Tensorflow doesn't support strides, how can I implement the above result efficiently. Thank you.